# Selected value is not comming as selected when insert failed in yii

Tags: php, yii, insert

I'm unable to get the selected value after the page refreshes due to validation failure at server-side for only `dropdownlist`.

Here is my code.

```
    $model=new Employee;

    if(isset($_POST['Employee']))
    {
        $_POST['Employee']['acc_id'] = Yii::app()->session['acc_id'];
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Employee'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->emp_id));
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

and my dropdown list in `_form.php` in `views`

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'emp_type'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Employee[emp_type]', $model,Type::model()->jobTypesList,
        array('empty' => 'Select a job type'))?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'emp_type'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Employee[emp_type]', $model,Type::model()->jobTypesList,array('empty' => 'Select a job type'))?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'emp_type', Type::model()->jobTypesList,array('empty' => 'Select a job type'))?>
```

Comment: entire form names are generated as Employee array values i.e for text fields and they are working fine

Comment: check with my edit or use `CHtml::activeDropDownList` refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail